# I18n.locale doesn't inherits from I18n.default_locale defined in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, i18n-gem, rails-i18n

I created a new rails 3.2.12 application and in application.rb i use to configure the default locale like this 
      `config.i18n.default_locale = "pt-PT"`

I had all the locales yml in the place and after running the server the translations doesn't work. 
When i debug it immediately after the default_locale attribution and print the value of config.i18n.locale it had nil, and it's not suppose to...it should return 'pt-PT'

Any suggestion about what is happening here?